# Is there a way to change the old MFC browser window by using CEF?

Tags: css, mfc, chromium-embedded

I can load my html code inside the MFC window however I can't seem to change the style of the window itself?
Currently I have the old windows browser:

[image]

But I want something like this where I can change the colour, buttons and border of the browser window.

[image]

From what I found you cannot change the way the window looks in MFC so is there a possible way to change it using CEF? I was thinking maybe CSS could do it but it only affects the HTML inside the window.

Comment: What version of MFC do you have for your project ?

Comment: Hi, looks like I am using version 14. 'MFC_VER 0x0E00 // Microsoft Foundation Classes version 14.00'

Answer (score 1):

In your stdafx.h do you have this code ?

```
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
```

If you do, just activate it and you will have the desired look then.

P.S. Be sure lines from above should not be avoided by your compiler by *#define* directives. If that lines are active, they should improve your frame windows as you wish.

Comment: Those directives can be placed into any translation unit. It's unusual to have them in a header file, particularly when that header file is included multiple times. After all, it's sufficient for the linker directives to be contained in any single .obj file.

Comment: That directives are automatically generated on project creation, on that stdafx.h file.

Comment: Maybe so, but that doesn't invalidate my comment. It's not prohibited to question the decision made by others. And placing this linker directive into multiple .obj files is just needless.

Comment: I have no intention to invalidate your answer, and any answer as well :) ... I just inform you that these lines are put there automatically. Anyway, thanks for your information.

Comment: @flaviu2 Can you elaborate on the answer a bit. I had this line in my 'stdafx.h': #if _MSC_VER >= 1400
 #pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif                                                                      but how will that change the browser frame? how can I change it after I make this change. CSS doesn't seem to affect the window, only the html inside it. Do I use CEF to do this somehow?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please try the code what I have sent you (from my answer), and see if your frame windows looks what you want.